# Identification question when the book is not SF?

Tags: discussion, scope

I scrolled through the list of SE sites, and didn't see anything promising.  I've been trying to find a particular book for some time, but it isn't sci-fi or fantasy.  Thus, not only may it be off-topic here, but probably not likely to find the answer here.

I tried what I thought was an exact quote on Google Books, but no result.  Probably I got the quote slightly wrong.

Is there a good place for such a question?  The book was about Pearl Harbor, and what was so memorable (and the reason I want to find it again) was the **stupid** first lines, something like

> It was a day like any other.  Fathers getting ready for work; children
>   getting ready for school.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We have a [Literature](http://literature.stackexchange.com/) site... They answer ID questions about books.